# htmlagilitypack: Find second table within a div

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse information from a `div` that has 3 tables within it. I can get information from the first one without problem.

Code so far as follow:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldocObject = doc.Load(URL);
var res = htmldocObject.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='BoxContent']");

var firstTable = res.SelectSingleNode("//table");
var charName = firstTable.ChildNodes[i++].InnerText.Substring(5).Trim();

<div class="BoxContent">
    <table>
        <tr bgcolor=#505050>
            <td colspan=2 class=white>
            <b>I'm getting this text</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor=#F1E0C6>
            <td>I get this too</td>
            <td>I'm getting this as well</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Trying to retrieve this</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I find the second table information with HAP?

I've read some about nextsibling function but I can't get it to work.

Comment: i think you forgot to copy/paste the declaration of i as int

Comment: please paste your code correctly because it does not match your explanation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var secondTable = res.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the collection of table inside the div this way

```
foreach(HtmlNode table in doc.res.SelectNodes("//table"])
{
  if(table != null)
  {
    var charName = table.InnerText.Substring(5).Trim();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try going directly for the `<td>` tags instead by changing your Xpath string.

```
HtmlNodeCollection tdNodeCollection = htmldocObject
                                     .DocumentNode
                                     .SelectNodes("//div[@class = 'BoxContent']//td");

foreach (HtmlNode tdNode in tdNodeCollection)
{
     Console.WriteLine(tdNode.InnerText);
}
```