# Access the second div nodes with the same class name

Tags: web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm confused trying to access the second container with the same attribute

so far I'm able to access this the section nodes with HTMLagilitypack

need help guys,
thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you specify exact `div` element on the image?

Comment: Please show the code you have so far as well as input and expected output

Comment: var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = web.Load(page);

            var Article = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//main//div[@id='sp']//div[@class='container']//div[@class='sp__content']//div[@class='sp__products']//div[@id='sp__products--list']//form//section[@class='pc__footer']//div[@class='pi pi__default sp__sizer']");

Comment: sorry still new in this platform

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htmlagilitypack: Find second table within a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675630/htmlagilitypack-find-second-table-within-a-div)